# How to use Pearson Chi-squared test on several vaiables

Tags: statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, independence

In R I have 2 datasets: `group1` and `group2`.

For `group 1` I have 10 `game_id` which is the id of a game, and we have `number` which is the numbers of times this games has been played in `group1`.

So if we type

```
group1
```

we get this output

```
game_id  number
1        758565
2        235289
...
10       87084
```

For `group2` we get

```
game_id  number
1        79310
2        28564
...
10       9048
```

If I want to test if there is a statistical difference between `group1` and `group2` for the first 2 `game_id` I can use Pearson chi-square test.

In R I simply create the matrix

```
# The first 2 'numbers' in group1
a <- c( group1[1,2] , group1[2,2] )
# The first 2 'numbers' in group2
b <- c( group2[1,2], group2[2,2] )
# Creating it on matrix-form
m <- rbind(a,b)
```

So `m` gives us

```
a 758565  235289
b 79310  28564
```

Here I can test H: "a is independent from b", meaning that users in `group1` play `game_id` 1 more than 2 compared to `group2`.

In R we type `chisq.test(m)` and we get a very low p-value meaning that we can reject H, meaning that a and b is not independent.

How should one find `game_id`'s that are played significantly more in `group1` than in `group2` ?